# Internal II(S) website works on HTTP(S) but not HTTP

Tags: iis-7.5

I setup an internal website on IIS 7.5 that can only be accessible by other computers on the network. The public has no access to my web server. It works only when I access it through HTTPS, but not HTTP. Why?

Note: All firewall settings on the machine where the web server is running are shut off.

Below is my port bindings for both HTTPS and HTTP.

```
Type: HTTP
IP address: 192.168.1.1
Port: 301
Host name: "Blank"

Type: HTTPS
IP address: 192.168.1.1
Port: 302
Host name: "Blank"
IIS Certificate: IIS Express Development Certificate
```

Web browser error for HTTP:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection 192.168.1.1 sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Comment: What is `192.168.1.222` in your network?

Comment: typo. supposed to be 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Use Fiddler/Wireshark to check what exactly happens, or simply use a simple browser like IE. Other browsers might automatically attempt to connect via HTTPS at port 443.